# ADAL not passing over CORS header

Tags: angular, cors, adfs, adal

I've created a angular 5 application that uses adal-angular5 package to log in a user through ADFS 2016. The angular application also connects to an API which retrieves data from & sends data to a corresponding database. The angular application is located at https://localhost:4200, while the api is located at https://localhost:44377. Once I added the Authorize attribute on the api endpoint to verify the id_token being passed from the application, I started receiving a CORS failure on Chrome.

The actual failure message is "Failed to load extracted-adfs-url: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

The configuration for the adal5Service:

```
const config = {
      instance: 'https://my.adfs.server.url/',
      tenant: 'adfs',
      clientId: 'E1CF1107-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-36052DD2C714',
      redirectUrl: 'https://localhost:4200/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://localhost:4200/',
      endpoints: {
        'https://localhost:44377/api/price' : 'E1CF1107-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-36052DD2C714'
      }
    };
```

The angular service that points to the authorized endpoint:

```
private headers = this.getHeaders();

getPriceItemDetails(): Observable<PriceItemDetail[]> {
    const url = `${this.domainRoute}/${this.baseUrl}`;
    return this.httpClient
      .get<PriceItemDetail[]>(url, { headers: this.headers })
      .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
  }

  private getHeaders() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', this.domainRoute);
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.service.userInfo.token}`);
    return headers;
  }
```

The API Cors configuration:

```
<add key="cors:allowOrigins" value="https://localhost:4200"/>

var origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:allowOrigins"];
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST,OPTIONS");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The API Endpoint:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/price")]
public class PriceController : ApiController
{
    private RepoPrice _repoPrice;

    public PriceController()
    {
        _repoPrice = new RepoPrice();
    }

    [Route()]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<PriceItemDetail>))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPriceItem()
    {
        // redacted code
    }
}
```

ADFS Setup for Angular:

```
RedirectUri                          : {https://localhost:4200/}
Name                                 : Angular App
Description                          :
ClientId                             : E1CF1107-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-36052DD2C714
BuiltIn                              : False
Enabled                              : True
ClientType                           : Public
ADUserPrincipalName                  :
ClientSecret                         :
LogoutUri                            :
JWTSigningCertificateRevocationCheck : None
JWTSigningKeys                       : {}
JWKSUri                              :
```

ADFS Setup for API:

```
AllowedAuthenticationClassReferences : {}
EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck : CheckChainExcludeRoot
PublishedThroughProxy                : False
SigningCertificateRevocationCheck    : CheckChainExcludeRoot
WSFedEndpoint                        : https://localhost:44377/
AdditionalWSFedEndpoint              : {}
ClaimsProviderName                   : {}
ClaimsAccepted                       : {}
EncryptClaims                        : True
Enabled                              : True
EncryptionCertificate                :
Identifier                           : {https://localhost:44377}
NotBeforeSkew                        : 0
EnableJWT                            : False
AlwaysRequireAuthentication          : False
Notes                                :
OrganizationInfo                     :
ProxyEndpointMappings                : {}
ProxyTrustedEndpoints                : {}
ProtocolProfile                      : WsFed-SAML
RequestSigningCertificate            : {}
EncryptedNameIdRequired              : False
SignedSamlRequestsRequired           : False
SamlEndpoints                        : {}
SamlResponseSignature                : AssertionOnly
SignatureAlgorithm                   : http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
TokenLifetime                        : 0
AllowedClientTypes                   : Public, Confidential
IssueOAuthRefreshTokensTo            : AllDevices
RefreshTokenProtectionEnabled        : True
RequestMFAFromClaimsProviders        : False
ScopeGroupId                         :
Name                                 : localhost:44377
AutoUpdateEnabled                    : False
MonitoringEnabled                    : False
MetadataUrl                          :
ConflictWithPublishedPolicy          : False
IssuanceAuthorizationRules           : @RuleTemplate = "AllowAllAuthzRule"
                                        => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit",                                        Value = "true");


IssuanceTransformRules               : @RuleTemplate = "LdapClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "AD-UPN"
                                       c:[Type ==
                                       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname",                                        Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
                                        => issue(store = "Active Directory", types =
                                       ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query =
                                       ";userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);


DelegationAuthorizationRules         :
LastPublishedPolicyCheckSuccessful   :
LastUpdateTime                       : 12/31/1899 6:00:00 PM
LastMonitoredTime                    : 12/31/1899 6:00:00 PM
ImpersonationAuthorizationRules      :
AdditionalAuthenticationRules        :
AccessControlPolicyName              :
AccessControlPolicyParameters        :
ResultantPolicy                      :
```

I have other endpoints that do not have the authorize attribute on the API endpoint, which are still working with the CORS headers used above. My assumption is there is a setting that was missed when setting up the ADFS connection, but I could not find what it could be.

Any help on how to resolve my CORS issue with the browser would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the Angular service, it must be a response header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my endpoint parameter. I set the endpoint to a specific endpoint within the api, rather than just the generic api endpoint. The correct way to set endpoint is

```
endpoints: {
    'https://localhost:44377/api/' : 'E1CF1107-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-36052DD2C714'
  }
```